# Don't get data from facebook when restart myapp

Tags: android, xamarin, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on xamarin Android Application.I am using Fascebook-SDK for facebook-login through myapp.When I run my app and click on facebook button I get all the data which I ask for but though I am still logged in ,if I close myapp without logging out and restart myapp it showing no any data
What is the problem ?
even I call this to get user data back when I restart or start my app but not working:

```
 protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(this,new List<string>{"public_profile","user_friends"});
        base.OnStart ();
    }

 protected override void OnRestart ()
    {
        LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(this,new List<string>{"public_profile","user_friends"});
        base.OnRestart ();
    }
```